# Hide inherited content/schemas

Tags: tridion

I'm working with a Publication that is low in our tridion Blueprint hierarchy.  Some of the content & schemas that are being inherited from Publications higher in the Blueprint are inappropriate for my Publication & will never be used by my Publication.

I'm going to follow up with the internal team that added those items & try & convince them that either:

1. these items should be in a different Publication or
2. our Blueprint needs to be tweaked.

If that goes nowhere, what are my options?  Can I hide the content/schemas that I don't want?  Also, it seems that it would helpful if the Blueprint had more fine-grained control over what exactly, I am inheriting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can control what's visible. Since inheritance (sharing) is separate from publishing, it's typically a good idea to:

- Share schemas, Category definitions, and possibly shared templating functionality (e.g. TBBs)
- Share, but hide components through folder permissions
- Limit schema and template visibility per publication using subfolders

## **BluePrint Change?**

Separate content publications (to avoid sharing) makes sense for certain scenarios:

- **Legal requirements.** To meet legal or auditing requirements to avoid *commercial information* on a non-profit website, you might use two publications or a setup where commercial falls *below* non-profit content.
- **Multi-tenancy.** Not common, but if you have a multi-tenant scenario which uses the same CMS but separate content, your "customers" would appreciate separate content publications.
- **Internal content.** Intranets or other very sensitive information are "safer" when placed parallel or above global content publications.

If these don't apply, it's a good idea to share at least content. You'll want schemas in a separate, higher publication.

## Share Structure and Definitions

Even if content should be in different publications, it's a good idea to share the "structure" or schema definitions for the components. A single schema publication can hold embeddable/metadata/regular schemas, Categories, and some system-level folders without impacting templates or content.

## Content and Folders

It's actually a good idea to consolidate content into fewer shared content publications. This makes life much easier for authors, especially if you have a centralized content authoring team.

Even if in different groups, you can definitely "hide" non-relevant folders in child publications by doing the following:

- Remove read permissions to folders in the lower publication to groups that have scope for that publication
- Set the [MMC snap-in setting](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/gen_concept_382BF5DCD4BF401ABDE0B58D28E1B11C) `Hide organizational items if no access to content` to 1 (for true).

## Schemas and Templates

You can also limit the visibility of schemas and templates by:

- Placing schemas in subfolders with specific permissions. Only users and groups with read for those folders will be able to see and select the schemas in the component form view drop-down.
- Doing the same for templates will limit who can see which templates. Template selection is already limited when creating component presentations on a page--only the associated schemas for the component's schema are selectable in the drop-down.

Address a "will never be used by my Publication" requirement through groups and permission settings on folders. If it's a case of "*should* never be...", then consider a BluePrint change.

Edit: fixed where Intranet publications should go, it's parallel or *above* any Global Content.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the security model to hide Organizational Items in BluePrint children - just remove Read permissions for all Groups at the appropriate level. Of course, this is dependent on the relevant items not sharing Organizational Items with inherited items that should be available at that level.